# How can i detect "out of bound error" in C program with GDB?

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, gdb

I wrote this program in C, adding an intentional error on purpose.

The program calculates the sum of 5 numbers entered by the user, and displays the result on the screen.

I compiled it with "gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -pedantic -g" and works fine.

But it has an error.

In the last repetition of the cycle, the program evaluates a[N], which is not defined!

I'd like to know how to spot this kind of error using GDB

When i use "**set check range on**" i get this messange "warning: the current range check setting does not match the language." and nothing happens...

This is the code to debug:

```
#define N 5
#include <stdio.h>


void read(float*);


int main(void) {

    float a[N], s;

    int i;

    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", N);
    read(a);

    i = -1; 
    s = 0;

    while (i != N) {
        i = i + 1;
        s = s+a[i];
    }

    printf("The sum is : %.2f \n", s);

    return 0;
}


void read(float*a) {

    int n = 0;

    while (n!=N) { 
        scanf("%f",&a[n]);
        n++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd give valgrind a shot, sounds like the hammer for this nail ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
while (i != N) {
    i = i + 1;
    s = s+a[i];
}
```

`N` is defined as `5`, so when `i` is 4, the condition is true. `i` is then incremented to 5, and `s += a[i];` is executed. Just use a `for` loop instead, or use `do {} while`:

```
for (i=0;i<N;++i)
    s += a[i];
//or
i = 0;
do {
   s += a[i];
} while (++i != N);
```

Either way. Personally, I find the `for` loop more readable

---

To answer your question (using gdb):

- You've compiled using the -g flag, so run `gdb compiled_file_name
- In gdb, set a break-point in the `while` loop (`b <line-nr> [condition]`)
- start the program (`run`)
- use `step` or `next` to step through the code
- use `p i` to check the value of `i` every time you hit the `while` condition, and every time you use `i` as offset (`a[i]`)

For more details, [docs for gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) are available. It takes some time, but it's well worth it. gdb is an excellent debugger

Comment: Yes, i know what the problem is . The error was introduced intentionally . The question is how can it be detected using GDB ?

Comment: @JavierMoreno: added a quick how-to to my answer. It's basic stuff, setting breakpoints, stepping and viewing the variables

Comment: @JavierMoreno: Added a link to gdb docs. PS: If you find an answer that  solved your problem (or answered your actual question), you are asked not to post _"thank you"_ comments, but [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) instead. It's the SO way of saying thanks + you get an extra 2 rep for it

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this particular error is that the loop increments i and then accesses a at index i, without an intervening check. So when i equals N - 1 when it starts the loop, it's incremented to N and used in the array.

In general, gcc's -fsanitize=bounds option should be helpful for these errors.